# Onfocus() event of Javascript is not calculating textbox value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my asp.net website I am trying to multiply two textbox value and store it into another textbox. But, my piece of code is not working

The JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
function myFunction(x)
{
var x = document.getElementById("<%=u_price1.ClientID %>") * document.getElementById("<%=qty1.ClientID %>");
return x;
}
</script>
```

Textboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="u_price1" runat="server" Width="63px" CssClass="txt1">0</asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="qty1" runat="server" Width="63px" CssClass="txt1">0</asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="amt1" runat="server" Width="81px" CssClass="txt1" onfocus="myFunction(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please tell me whats wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious thing that jumps out at me is you're using the multiply operator (`*`) against two DOM elements, which will return `NaN`.  That is,

```
document.getElementById("<%=u_price1.ClientID %>")
```

Is returning an object, not the numeric value of the contents of that text box.  What I think you want to do is get the text box's *value*:

```
var x = document.getElementById("<%=u_price1.ClientID %>").value *
    document.getElementById("<%=qty1.ClientID %>").value;
```

If you want to be really defensive, you can check to make sure they're valid numbers:

```
var price = Number( document.getElementById("<%=u_price1.ClientID %>").value );
var qty = Number( document.getElementById("<%=qty1.ClientID %>").value );
```

Then you can check to make sure they're valid numbers:

```
if( isNaN( price ) || isNaN( qty ) ) {
    // take appropriate error handling action here
}
```

However, there may be other things going on with your script.  I would put a `console.log` inside `myFunction` to make sure it's even getting called.  If it's not getting called, then something else is wrong, but you definitely have to fix the object multiplication problem.

Comment: Function is being called. @Yury after your modification I tried this too. But still its not working.

Comment: @user3050674 Did you really read Ethan's or Yury's answer? The keyword is `value`, you can't multiple HTMLElements with each other.

Comment: @Teemu Yes I have made necessary changes to it as per the suggestions given. But, in my asp.net page its not working. However, if I try to do anything else like changing the BG of textbox, its works fine.

Comment: Umesh, "not working" is pretty vague.  Are you getting errors on the console?  Is the code not executing?  Are you not getting the value you're expecting?  What *are* you getting?  You can't just say "it's not working" and expect us to be able to magically figure out what's wrong.  More details please.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction(x) {
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=u_price1.ClientID %>").value) || 0,
        qty = parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=qty1.ClientID %>").value, 10) || 0;
    x.value = price * qty.
}
```

1. You are multiplying two nodes, while you need values.
2. You need to convert string values to number.
3. You need to save the result of computation

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but still its not working.

Comment: @user3050674 Oh, inline handlers... Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I verified it in the HTML and it's working fine.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="first"></input>
<input type="text" id="second"></input>
<input type="text" id="result" onfocus="myFunction(this)"></input>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(x){
var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value) || 0,
        qty = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value, 10) || 0;
    x.value = price * qty;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you verify it and let me know if you still have issues.

Here is ASP.NET code:

We need to set ClientIDMode=Static for TextBox elements in order to access their fields in javascript other wise their ids will be changed.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtinput1" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtinput2" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtresult" onfocus="myFunction(this)"></asp:TextBox>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(x) {
            var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtinput1").value) || 0,
                    qty = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtinput2").value, 10) || 0;
            x.value = price * qty;
        }
    </script>

</asp:content>
```

Let me know if this helps. I used onfocus and it works for onblur as well.

Comment: I am trying to do this in ASP.Net. Well, currently I want to implement it using TextChange event of asp.net. Let me see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this solution...     
<script language="javascript">
        function myFunction()
        {
         var u_price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("u_price1").value);
         var qty1= parseInt(document.getElementById("qty1").value);
         var x = u_price1 * qty1;
         document.getElementById("amt1").value = x;
        }
        </script>

        <html>
        <body>
        <input type="text" ID="u_price1" name="u_price1"  Width="63px" CssClass="txt1"/>
        <input type="text"  ID="qty1" name="qty1" Width="63px" CssClass="txt1"/>
        <input type="text"  ID="amt1" name="amt1" Width="81px" CssClass="txt1" onfocus="myFunction()"/>
        </body>
        </html>
```